# How do i contain text inside a user defined box using css?

Tags: html, css, image, text, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to float text beside an image but it always gets shoved to the bottom of it. I have floated one to the right and one to the left with no avail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Is this by any chance what you're looking for?
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/A7F1De?p=preview)

css

```
.myClass {
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
}
img {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="myClass">
      <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      <p>This is some text besides a photo</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </body>

</html>
```